# Ajax post to PHP redirects instead of return result

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post, file-upload

I'm trying to make a PHP-page for uploading user avatars, but I want the selected picture to be updated automatically after file-selection (possibly with a dialog to confirm change of avatar). So far I've got the auto-upload bit working, but I'm having trouble using the POST-function to my external PHP-file. While testing, instead of returning the results back to Ajax, it redirects to the external PHP-file and echoes the result there. I'm sure there is some basic thing I'm overlooking, but I would love to get some help as I can't seem to my head around it. I've previously managed to get the results back to Ajax in the success-function, but here it doesn't alert (only redirects). I've yet to implent the file-uploading bit, but I have that working on another section of the site so I only need to get this code working.

So basically what I want answered is;

- How can I get the callback without redirecting?
- How (and where) should I implement a confirm-dialog before the POST to uploadavatar.php?

Here is the code.

HTML / Javascript / Ajax

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start();
include_once 'header.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
function chooseAvatar() { $("#avatarInput").click();}

$('form#avatarForm').submit( function( e ) {
e.preventDefault();

  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

  $.ajax( {
  url: 'uploadavatar.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (returndata) {
  alert(returndata);
} });
return false;
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<section>

<h1>Edit your profile: <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']) ?></h1>
<article>
<div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden">
<form action="uploadavatar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="avatarForm" id="avatarForm">
<input type="file" id="avatarInput" name="avatarInput" />
<script>
$("input[name='avatarInput']").change(function() {
  $( 'form#avatarForm' ).submit();
});
</script>
</form>
</div>
<p><span class='label_viewprofile'>Avatar (65x65):</span><img src="avatar/avatar.jpg" class="avatar-box" onclick="chooseAvatar();"></p>
<hr class="editprofile-line">

</article>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

External 'uploadavatar.php' file

```
<?php
echo  "Working!";
print_r ($_FILES);
print_r ($_POST);
?>
```

Thank you so much for any help or input! I'm new to programming in these languages, so all feedback is appreciated.

**EDIT 29/4-15**:
- Posted the full code now. Had two other forms and more code on the page that I removed to check if there was any conflict, but this is the code I'm working with now. *Still* redirecting and not giving 'returndata' to Ajax, and I've had no luck removing the form "action=" part either (didn't appear to post or redirect). Again, I am very grateful for the time and effort you people put into helping me. I have very little experience with JS and Ajax, but I'm ordering a book to learn more, so thanks again!

Comment: There is nothing in this code which performs a redirect.

Comment: Your form has an `action` of "uploadavatar.php", which will try to redirect to that page. Simply remove that action.

Comment: You don't have to do that @xathien because the OP uses a `preventDefault()` in the AJAX code.

Comment: Which will work once he follows Twisty's answer. :)

Comment: Actually, removing the `action` of "uploadavatar.php" gave no action at all. Could this mean that my JS code isn't properly executed? Again, thank you very much for you input. I've updated the code, so hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.
You called the wrong event (e), not (event):

```
$('form#avatarForm').submit( function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

This will prevent the page from being submitted, and then use the `$.ajax()`.

**EDIT:**

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0feqyqmw/

Made a few changes overall, but this should work:

```
$(function () {
    $("#avatarBtn").click(function () {
        $("#avatarInput").click();
    });

    $("input[name='avatarInput']").on("change", function(){
        $('form#avatarForm').submit();
    });

    $('form#avatarForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'uploadavatar.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (returndata) {
                alert(returndata);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I moved all your script into JQuery for ease of use. I also added a bit of wrapping in your HTML:

```
<section>
     <h1>Edit your profile: UserName</h1>

    <article>
        <div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden">
            <form action="uploadavatar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="avatarForm" id="avatarForm">
                <input type="file" id="avatarInput" name="avatarInput" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <p> <span class='label_viewprofile'>Avatar (65x65):</span>

            <label id="avatarBtn">
                <img src="avatar/avatar.jpg" class="avatar-box" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <hr class="editprofile-line">
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Good eye, Twisty! I missed that. I updated the code to event.preventDefault, but it still redirects.

Comment: Which did you update? the `$('form#avatarForm').submit( function( e ) {` to `event` or the `event.preventDefault();` to `e`?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough there. I named them both event. Like this;
      `$( 'form#avatarForm' ).submit( function( event ) {event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Try: `$("#avatarForm").on("submit", function( event ) {`

Comment: If it still give you issues, add `console.log()`. Something is not right in the JS somewhere... check your console. Post all your code. If the `preventDefault()` is not triggering, it suggests code issues preventing the function you are trying to execute from running.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - you're definitely onto something. Never used console.log() before, but tested it and I got this from the browser;
"Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead."

Comment: Not familiar with that function. Check your code for a reference to that. Maybe a typo?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. I posted the full code now (after removing most of it to check for conflicts as I had another form on the page as well). Again, might be something very simply I've overlooked, so if it makes more sense now - let me know.